# string enum で値からキーを取得したい

Tags: typescript

TypeScript 2.5.3 において、コンパイルオプション **strict** で以下のコードをトランスパイルすると、エラーが出ます。

```
enum Animal {
    Cat = 'ねこ',
    Dog = 'いぬ'
}
const key = Animal['ねこ'];
```

> error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

enum の中身が数値のときは、上のエラーを出さずに値からキーの文字列を取り出すことができます。
`--strict` オプションを付けたまま、文字列値の enum に対してキーを逆引きすることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 補足: 回答を書いていた質問がその回答を投稿する前に削除されたので、ほぼ同じ内容の質問を投稿して自己回答してみました。他の回答も是非お願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

値からキーを逆引きできる機能は reverse mapping と呼ばれていますが、TypeScrip 2.5 現在、この機能はメンバーが number 型である enum で使うことが想定されています。特に、string 型のメンバに対しては実装されていません。実際 TypeScript の[ドキュメント](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)にも

> Keep in mind that string enum members do not get a reverse mapping generated at all.

と書かれています。これは実装上 enum のキーは string であり、キーと値の型が同じだと面倒だからです (たとえば文字列として同一なキーと値があるときに困ります)。このことは一般の型に対する enum を導入した[この issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1206#issuecomment-243622789) でも議論されています。

---

ですが、型の恩恵を無視してしまうなら、any 型にキャストしてしまうことでコンパイルを通し、reverse mapping 相当の動作をさせることはできます。この場合、変なことになっていないかは自分で確認する必要があります。

```
// dirty hack
enum Animal {
    Cat = <any>'ねこ',
    Dog = <any>'いぬ'
}
const key = Animal[<any>'ねこ']  // ==> 'Cat'
```

あるいは、以下のように自前の関数として実装してしまう方法があります。これは手間ですが any 型を使うことはなくなります。

```
enum Animal {
    Cat = 'ねこ',
    Dog = 'いぬ'
}

function animal(key: string): string | undefined {
    switch (key) {
    case 'ねこ':
      return 'Cat'
    case 'いぬ':
      return 'Dog'
    default:
      return undefined;
    }
}

const key = animal('ねこ');
```

また、本家 Stack Overflow の ["Reverse-Mapping for String Enums"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44883072/5989200) という質問も参考になるかもしれません。